# Why does multiplication with and without parentheses make a big difference?

Tags: c, parentheses, multiplication

If I multiply without parentheses to get a Fahrenheit number I get a different number than if I multiply with them. Why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    double userinput, fahr1, fahr2;

    printf("Enter a number in Cels ");
    scanf("%lf", &userinput);

    fahr1 = userinput*(9/5)+32;
    fahr2 = userinput*9/5+32;

    printf("fahr1 = %f and fahr2 = %f \n", fahr1, fahr2);

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Enter a number in Cels 15
fahr1 = 47.000000 and fahr2 = 59.000000
```

Comment: `(9/5)` is treated as integer division. So it evaluates to `1`.

Answer (score 5):

`(9/5)` is integer division, and evaluates to `1`.  But `userinput*9` is evaluated as a double, and then division by 5 is treated as a double as well.

Comment: Ohh Thanks! So in the future I should do 9.0/5.0 to be safe...

Comment: @GY-Z, indeed, this is stated in first chapter of "The C programming language", which is probably the book you are following.

Comment: Actually I learn everything from videos. So YouTube and moocs. Only read if I have to.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is very easy

Without the brackets: 15.0*9=135.00  135.0/5 = 27.00 27.0+32 = 59.00

With brackets: 9/5 = 1 (integer division) 15.0 * 1 = 15.0, 15.0 + 32 = 47.00

Answer (score 0):

Here

1)      userinput*(9/5)+32;

```
    15.0*(1)+32   //1.8 goes to 1 because integer division
    15.0+32
    47.0
```

2)      userinput*9/5+32;

```
    15.0*9/5+32
    135.0/5+32
    27.0+32
    59.0
```